# HTML - Images and text not following table properly

Tags: html, css

I have one known-problem: text and images that should be below the table are in the wrong place (see screenshot)

[image: screenshot of improper layout]

```css
.openingtimes {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1" align="right">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Saturday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1700</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="openingtimes">
  <br>
  <b>All major card types accepted including contactless </b><br>
  <br>
  <img src="https://stylebyjulie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/paymentmethods.png" alt="style by julie payment methods" width="227" height="28" align="right">
  <br><br>
  <b>Supporting (click to find out more)</b><br><br>
  <a href="https://stylebyjulie.co.uk/little-princess-trust/">
    <img title="little princess trust" src="https://stylebyjulie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/littleprincess-logo.png" alt="little princess trust" width="138" height="111" align="right"></a>
</div>
```

The content should all be aligning to the right.

The text and images should be below the table in this order

1. Table
2. "all major card types accepted" text
3. card types img
4. "supporting" text
5. Little princess trust img

PS: I am new to HTML so if you have any feedback on my code feel free to include. Always looking to learn and improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align="right"` attribute on your table was breaking the layout but this has [been deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html) and shouldn't be used. I've used `margin-inline: auto 0` on your table instead that pushes the table to the right. Here's a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Azfj1efPAH0) from Kevin Powell to help you. If you're new to HTML and CSS his videos are a very good introduction.

```css
.openingtimes {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

table {
  margin-inline: auto 0; /* added this */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Saturday</td>
        <td>0900 - 1700</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="openingtimes">
  <br>
  <b>All major card types accepted including contactless </b><br>
  <br>
  <img src="https://stylebyjulie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/paymentmethods.png" alt="style by julie payment methods" width="227" height="28" align="right">
  <br><br>
  <b>Supporting (click to find out more)</b><br><br>
  <a href="https://stylebyjulie.co.uk/little-princess-trust/">
    <img title="little princess trust" src="https://stylebyjulie.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/littleprincess-logo.png" alt="little princess trust" width="138" height="111" align="right"></a>
</div>
```